# Parallelism on a single processor system

Tags: concurrency, parallel-processing, operating-system, cpu-architecture

Can we apply the concept of parallelism on a single processor system. Let's say for example if we have two processes A & B and they are independent of each other, can they be simultaneously taken care (executed) of, if so how? Can you please explain in terms of the execution cycle that would follow.

Comment: yes through time sharing and context switching

Comment: Well, no.  They cannot simultaneously be executed.  They are executed serially.  Probably just semantics.

Comment: which I got from this question is he is misunderstanding that B will start after completion of A. I think OP is considering this. Am I right @Ashish

Comment: Even on a multi-core CPU, independent threads can be serialised if they both need to access main memory, or some other common resource such as a data bus, at the same time. On one architecture I've used the high precision clock hardware was at the end of a slow I2C bus. Accessing it took ages, and two threads both making requests were very obviously serialised by this!

Answer (score 4):

They cannot run simultaneously if there is only a single processor.  If you have a multi-thread or multi-process environment, it will time slice each process and/or thread.  Only one will run at any given time, and there is overhead at each [context switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch).

> The precise meaning of "context switch" varies significantly in usage, most often to mean "thread switch or process switch" or "process switch only", either of which may be referred to as a "task switch". More finely, one can distinguish thread switch (switching between two threads within a given process), process switch (switching between two processes), mode switch (domain crossing: switching between user mode and kernel mode within a given thread), register switch, a stack frame switch, and address space switch (memory map switch: changing virtual memory to physical memory map). The computational cost of context switches varies significantly depending on what precisely it entails, from little more than a subroutine call for light-weight user processes, to very expensive, though typically much less than that of saving or restoring a process image.

On an interesting historical note, there were even multi-threading libraries available for MS-DOS before Windows became popular.  Many mainframe and mini computers from the same era employed the technique as well.

Comment: It's worth adding that a time slice can actually be quite long - perhaps 60ms, depending on the operating system. That's short enough for execution to appear to be simultaneous to a human, but it's a long time on a modern computer.

Comment: So when we have a process that is forked, it spawns it's children, theoretically it's said that it's children(spawned processes) are executed simultaneously, so how does that work out in a single processor environment ?  Say S1 and S2 are spawned from a process S, then in theory S1 and S2 execute simultaneously and say they join to start a process S3. So here how S1 and S2 are concurrently executed ? I hope it's  clear now. Please refer the link as an example for more clarity [link] (http://nob.cs.ucdavis.edu/classes/ecs251-2000-01/sync-1.gif). Thanks

Comment: If there is one CPU, each process is time-sliced onto that one physical CPU.  The processes take turns.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of having something like parallelism is called multitasking for single processor. We have to understand that when we have one core, that means no matter how many process(task) are there in system, only one can be executed at a time.

But if a process have threads, all the threads will be assigned to cpu one by one and user will have impression that all the threads of process are running.

Comment: `But if a process have threads, all the threads will be assigned to cpu one by one`  The same is true for a system that has multiple processes but only one CPU, or that has N processes and M CPUs where N > M (probably the case on your computer right now).

Comment: @Eric what I exactly meant was that only one task will be executed in 1 time unit when we have one core, but if number of core > 1, then number of task that can be executes in 1 time unit will be equal to number of core.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you, just adding some more information.

Answer (score 0):

The cpu is to be switched between processes.It is called context switching in OS.
There are different methods for context switching like:
round robin,priority queue
Above method will decide that which process will use cpu.
But cpu can't be used by two processes at a time.
In advance OS task scheduler is responsible to assign process to cpu.